# How to update multiple rows with primary key variable in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, where-clause

I have a table that is unique by primary key, and would like to update select rows by passing in an array.

However, I get the following error when trying to execute the stored procedure:

> Incorrect syntax near '@indices'

Sample data:

```
key | someColumn
----+-----------
1   | data
2   | more data
3   | even more data
```

Query:

```
declare @indices nvarchar(max) = [1,2,3,...] -- this set by actually set by API

update thisTable 
set someColumn = 'data to update with',
where [i] in @indices;
```

Where `indices = [1,2,3,...]`.

How can I pass in an array of keys to check against to update the table?

Comment: I would do this update with a join.

Comment: What would a join look like in this case?

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use the STRING_SPLIT function in the following manner:

```
UPDATE thisTable
SET    someColumn = 'Some Value'
WHERE  [i] IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@indices, ','));
```

If you are using earlier versions, you will need to resort to some uglier solutions, you can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns):

HTH

```
-- For SQL Server 2016
ALTER DATABASE [database_name_here]
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130 
GO
```

Comment: Excellent, but he will also need to fix the declare to replace the `[ ]` with `' '` : `declare @indices nvarchar(max) = '1,2,3,...'`

Comment: Getting an errror `Invalid object name 'string_split'` with SQL Server version `Microsoft SQL Server 2017`.

Comment: @Matthew make sure your database compatibility level is set to 130 or higher, also check the examples in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: oops - I was also missing a close parenthesis character in my example, fixed now...

Comment: Compatibility level change fixed it. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by executing the entire query storing it in a variable.  Caution, as this type of code could be vulnerable to SQL injection if API  uses a parameter provided by a user.

```
DECLARE @indices NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'1,2,3'

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'update thisTable set someColumn = 'data to update with'
 Where [i] in (' + @indices+ ')'

Exec (@query)
```